# Cross compile GTK+ application from Linux to Windows?

Tags: c, windows, linux, gtk, cross-compiling

How can I cross compile my GTK+ app (written in C) from Linux to Windows? Could I just replace the "gcc" command with "mingw32"?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora has a great mingw32 cross-compiler toolchain which comes with lots of precompiled libraries, including GTK+ and gtkmm. For most applications you just need to install the cross-compiler and the cross-compiled GTK+ libraries:
yum install mingw32-gcc mingw32-gtk2

Once everything needed is installed, compiling your application is just the matter of running "mingw32-configure" followed with "make".

More information at the project page https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/MinGW

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mingw-cross-env](http://mingw-cross-env.nongnu.org/) - all you have to do then is to change your CC/CXX environment path to use the i686-mingw32- prefix and export the mingw-cross-env bin dirs (both) to your PATH variable (or if you are using autotool it's even easier) - see the documentation on the homepage.

Comment: not quite, picking up CFLAGS and stuff for GTK isn't quite that simple, you'd need to make sure pkg-config is looking in the right place

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a project called [MXE](https://mxe.cc) that does exactly this.

### Pre-build package

You can [download my pre-build binaries](https://gitlab.melroy.org/melroy/gtk-3-bundle-for-windows) if you want.

### Build from source

You can also build the code from scratch ideally also applying [this PR](https://github.com/mxe/mxe/pull/2788) to update to the latest GTK 3.24 version.

MXE has a easy wrapper (`x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-cmake`) to **cross-build** your project towards Windows, while using Linux. Allowing to evenly statically build your project into a single .exe file! Of course shared builds (`x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared-cmake`) are also supported. The example wrapper scripts are meant for CMake based projects.

Before you can build your project with MXE, you need to build the GTK3 from source-code. (There are some Linux packages available, but mostly out-dated). If you are using C++, you can also build `gtkmm3`. Since you are in place C, you only need to build `gtk3`.

1. `git clone https://github.com/mxe/mxe.git`
2. Become root user: `su`
3. `mv mxe /opt/mxe`
4. `cd /opt/mxe`
5. Build the MXE project yourself:

For static builds under Windows 64-bit for GTK3 & Gtkmm3:

```
sudo make gtk3 gtkmm3 -j 16 MXE_TARGETS='x86_64-w64-mingw32.static' MXE_PLUGIN_DIRS='plugins/gcc12'
```

For shared build to Windows 64-bit (again GTK3 + Gtkmm3):

```
sudo make gtk3 gtkmm3 -j 16 MXE_TARGETS='x86_64-w64-mingw32.shared' MXE_PLUGIN_DIRS='plugins/gcc12'
```

More info see the [tutorial steps on MXE.cc](https://mxe.cc/#tutorial).

Once you done the cross-compile environment / MXE build. Now you can use the CMake wrapper scripts I mentioned earlier. Those scripts are located in the `/opt/mxe/usr/bin/` directory.

The scripts (like `x86_64-w64-mingw32.static-cmake`) can now be used to compile your project towards Windows, while using the Linux operating system. The build result would be an Windows `.exe`.

**Disclaimer:** I personally created [this PR for MXE](https://github.com/mxe/mxe/pull/2788) to update GTK to the latest 3.24.x release.